# jQuery event registration undefines the element from FORM scope <ColdFusion>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

Today I came across a weird situation where an element registered using jQuery keyup (or any event for that matter) would undefine that element from the FORM scope upon submitting my form. I am using jQuery 1.4.4 version and a jQuery plugin named highlightTextarea. Has anyone faced this situation or is it just a novice mistake?

I did scour the internet for fixes, like library overriding, jQuery overriding and other conflicts. I tried changing my layout, selectors etc but did not have any luck. The moment I remove this event registration, everything works normal. I tried with different events and the result was same.

My jQuery code inside the document ready function:

```
$('#settlement_details').keyup(function (e) {
        updateCount($(this)); // updates the character count inside my textarea to a div

    });
```

My HTML:

```
  <table>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="4" class="formfield"><span class="formlabel">Settlement Details (Max 600 characters)</span><br>
               <textarea cols="60" data-maxlength="600" rows="5" id="settlement_details" name="settlement_details">#settlement_details#
               </textarea><br>
               Character Count:<span id="charNum"></span> 
          </td>
       </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: jQuery 1.4.4 ? That seems like an old version. I wonder if newer versions do not have this issue.

Comment: @JamesAMohler its an enhancement project and I do not have control over updating the libraries.

Comment: Regular submit or ajax? What is the code for `updateCount($(this));`?

Comment: @Ageax.. It is a regular form submit. The charcount function is just for illustration purpose. even if i do not put anything in the keyup function the issue exists.

Comment: @YoosafAbdulla - Weird. Tried a simple test but couldn't reproduce it. Test code. https://trycf.com/gist/3f388a17b47d3e8a26d36deeef76836c/lucee5?theme=monokai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i had to come up with was to have a hidden variable to copy the data to and have the submit and validations to work. I am not sure this is the perfect solution but the only one I could devise to.
My edited code was:

```
 $('#settlement_details').keyup(function (e) {
        updateCount($(this));
        $('input[name=settlement_details]').val($('#settlement_details').val());    
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="settlement_details" value="">
```